# Styling individual markers in markercluster

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am trying to style individual markers, or clusters of size 1, based on some feature property.

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  if (feature.properties.EncounterType && feature.properties.Year) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.EncounterType + " in " +
      feature.properties.Year);
  }
}

function style(feature) {
  switch (feature.properties.EncounterType) {
    case 'Shooting':
      return {
        color: "ff0000"
      };
    case 'Sighting':
      return {
        color: "0000ff"
      };
    case 'Hunting':
      return {
        color: "ff0000"
      };
  }
}

var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(storer, {
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}, {
  style: style
});

markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
map.addLayer(markers);
```

The `onEachFeature` function successfully creates the popups. However, the style function does not change the color of the clusters of size 1. I've tried using the `iconCreateFunction` when initializing the markerclustergroup, however, that did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `style` option is separated in a 3rd argument of your call to `L.geoJSON` factory, whereas it should have been placed within the 2nd argument, alongside `onEachFeature` option.

```js
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(storer, {
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
  style: style
});
```

But that is probably not the only reason for your issue.

[`style`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#geojson-style) option will apply to vector shapes (polylines, polygons, etc.), i.e. to non-point data. It may also apply to Circle Markers, which can be used for `Point` type geometries, but you have to explicitly create them (typically through the [`pointToLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#geojson-pointtolayer) option).

Those non-point data cannot be handled by Leaflet.markercluster.

Therefore if you see "clusters of size 1" (I guess you mean *markers*), they come from *unstyled* `Point` type geometries in your `storer` GeoJSON data.

This is a normal marker:

[image: Leaflet default marker]

It is a PNG image that *cannot* be styled.

If you want to customize the appearance of your `Point` geometries, use [custom icons](http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/), a [plugin](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#markers--renderers) that provide such custom icons, or [Circle Markers](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#circlemarker) which you can modify the colour easily (including through the `style` option).

For example, if you were to choose that last option, you could do something like:

```js
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(storer, {
  pointToLayer: function (geoJsonPoint, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng);
  },
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
  style: style
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That was an awesome explanation.

Comment: You are welcome. Please note that the SO way to thank people is also to _accept_ the answer that helped you solve your problems. When you get enough _reputation_, you will also have the possibility to _upvote_.

Comment: I realized I want to use a similar style function but on the feature property Year, with the different colors corresponding to different ranges of the year property. However, my Year property is a string not an integer. I was thinkig about using parseInt outside of the function to change the feature to an integer and mutate it back into the dataset/or a way to pass parseInt in the style function itself. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Please avoid mixing issues. Feel free to open a new question.

Comment: It would very probably work with that plugin (BTW it is not mine).